# Running an SQL query in background

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a modest dataset of 60k records with a value which takes a little time to compute. From a small trial run of 6k records in the production environment, it took 4 minutes to complete, so the full execution should take around 40 minutes.

However this trial run showed that there were SQL timeouts occurring on user requests when accessing data in related tables (but not necessarily on the actual rows which were being updated).

My question is, is there a way of running non-urgent queries as a background operation in the SQL server without causing timeouts or table locking for extensive periods of time? The data within the column which is being updated during this period is not essential to have the new value returned; aka if a request happened to come in for this row, returning the old value would be perfectly acceptable rather than locking the set until the update is complete (I'm not sure the ins and outs of how this works, obviously I do want to prevent data corruption; could be a way of queuing any additional changes in the background)

Comment: 6,000 records took 4 minutes? did you mean 6 million? What is the table ddl and related indexes? What does the update script look like? Are you using a cursor or some really slow user defined function in the update? What is the estimated execution plan for the update? Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: @SqlZim I'm updating it based upon a complex calculation where it tries to match or best guess a result where possible. It's been optimised, has the relevant indexes, and am not using cursors. It is what it is, and it's a one off update. The question isn't really about optimising this, but about how to maintain a level of service while this calculation occurs. One obvious method would be to do it in an isolated table and update the results, but I'm putting out feelers to see if there is any way that I can run this as a background process.

Comment: Does the calculation reference the table itself? If so if it takes 4 minutes for 6K records it may take considerably longer than 40 minutes for 60K records. E.g it could scale quadratically rather than linearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possibly a situation where the NOLOCK hint is appropriate.  You can read about SQL Server isolation levels in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql).  And Googling "SQL Server NOLOCK" will give you plenty of material on why you should not over-use the construct.

I might also investigate whether you need a *SQL query* to compute values.  A single query that takes 4 minutes on 6k records . . . well, that is a long time.  You might want to consider reading the data into an application (say, using Python, R, or whatever) and doing the data manipulation there.  It may also be possible to speed up the query processing itself.

Comment: You're probably right that an application would have been more efficient, as it is trying to predict/best guess a result where a match doesn't exist (especially as the items being processed are the scrapings of the barrel, ie. no direct matches). But in this case it has been written and is a one off exercises; I will give the NOLOCK a try and see if it prevents the timeout situation.